# Meteor mantra external client script

Tags: javascript, meteor

When using Meteor 1.3 with Mantra spec, what are the 'right' way and place to load external client script, I mean some JS library which has to be included client-side, with `<script>...</script>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

you can use npm or atmosphere for adding package or library. but if you want to add manualy using this meteor package [kadira:dochead](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-dochead)

use `meteor add kadira:dochead`

I created a addScript.js file inside `client/configs` with the following code:

```
import {DocHead} from 'meteor/kadira:dochead';

export default function () {
let addScript = 'https://link-to-your-script';
  DocHead.loadScript(addScript);
}
```

And imported it in `client/configs/context.js`